# How can I find temp files associated with an application?

Tags: windows-10, temporary-files

I am running an application that is supposed to read files from an hard disk but I see on Activity Monitor on Windows 10 that a lot of activity is taking place on another hard disk.

How can I find the temporary files created by that app, to check what is going on? The app is written using .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I find the temporary files created by that app?

You can use [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from Microsoft [SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb545021):

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more.
>
> Its uniquely powerful features will make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and malware hunting toolkit.
>
> **Overview of Process Monitor Capabilities**
>
> Process Monitor includes powerful monitoring and filtering capabilities, including:
>
> - More data captured for operation input and output parameters
> - Non-destructive filters allow you to set filters without losing data
> - Capture of thread stacks for each operation make it possible in many cases to identify the root cause of an operation
> - Reliable capture of process details, including image path, command line, user and session ID
> - Configurable and moveable columns for any event property
> - Filters can be set for any data field, including fields not configured as columns
> - Advanced logging architecture scales to tens of millions of captured events and gigabytes of log data
> - Process tree tool shows relationship of all processes referenced in a trace
> - Native log format preserves all data for loading in a different Process Monitor instance
> - Process tooltip for easy viewing of process image information
> - Detail tooltip allows convenient access to formatted data that doesn't fit in the column
> - Cancellable search
> - Boot time logging of all operations

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb545021) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.